# Automator: `command not found` (Python script for command line)

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, automator, python

I am trying to create an Automator application, which allows me to convert Python script files `.py` files to Jupyter Notebook files `.ipynb` using Python script for command line [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext). However, the following in the textbox of `Run Shell Scrip` of Automator generates an error command not found.

```
for f in "$@"
do
 jupytext --to notebook "$f"
done
```

This is despite the fact that no such error occurs if I run the following in Terminal on Mac.

```
jupytext --to notebook <filename>.py
```

Does anyone has any ideas about what is/are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you need to tell *Automator*'s shell instance where to locate the program `jupytext`.  Unless you saved `jupytext` somewhere specific on your hard drive, my guess is that the full path to `jupytext` is going to be `/usr/local/bin/jupytext`.  However, you can retrieve its location by opening up *Terminal* and using the command:

```
which jupytext
```

which will return the file path to the program.

Then, in your *Automator* action, replace `jupytext` with its full path, e.g.:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    /usr/local/bin/jupytext --to notebook "$f"
done
```